# Recursive query calculation time too long

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have the table `authors(name, conference, year)` where all 3 are primary keys.

Now I need to write a recursive query that returns all authors with distance <= 2 from author 'X'.

Distance is defined d(a1, a2)=1 if both a1 and a2 published at least 1 article in the same conference and in the same year.

Also d(a, a)=0.

So I was able to write a query that seems to work, but takes a few minutes. How can I improve it?

```
WITH RECURSIVE T(n, d, y, c) AS (
  SELECT name, 0, year, conference FROM authors
  WHERE name = 'X'
  UNION
  SELECT name, d + 1, year, conference
  FROM T, authors
  WHERE (d < 3) and ((y = year and c = conference) or (n = name)) )
SELECT distinct n AS name FROM T
ORDER BY name
```

Thanks!

Comment: Need a bit more info here.   How many authors are there?

Comment: you have to provide 1) sample data and desired output , 2) your query plan

Comment: For the sample data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emeryberger/CSrankings/gh-pages/generated-author-info.csv
As for the plan, it's an assignment I got so there's just what I wrote

Comment: "plan" means the query execution plan. See `EXPLAIN` in the dbms documentation

Comment: (Edit) Why do you think a recursive query is necessary here?  Also, "plan" means the query execution plan. See `EXPLAIN` in your dbms documentation